# Possible to make incremental checkpoints CRIU

Tags: docker, migration

I was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to make incremental checkpoints with CRIU, in particular when the process is Docker.

Also, I am interested in taking snapshots without killing the process.

My goal is to achieve fast, (almost) live migration procedure from a host to another.

It seems that with CRIU is impossible right now however I've seen videos of people doing it and I thought that after almost a year of most of these articles being posted I might be missing something here.

Comment: can u share the links of people doing incremental checkpoints using `criu`. I do not find any.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, same concern.
what you need is predumm option.

1. one resource may help. 
   github.com/xemul/p.haul
   p.haul make it possible to adjust predump request
2. runC with predump option.this is what you watch on youtube.15dockerCon.
   github.com/marcosnils/runc

Currently, we have serval ways to make docker checkpoint/restore.
a.
Native way:github.com/boucher/docker/releases

```
docker checkpoint
docker restore
```

b.runC way:github.com/marcosnils/cmt
github.com/marcosnils/runc

```
runc checkpoint 
runc restore
```

c.external way:

```
criu dump -o dump.log -v4 -t 15215 \
  -D /tmp/m1  \
  --root /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/container id  \
  --manage-cgroups \
  --evasive-devices \
  --ext-mount-map /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf \
  --ext-mount-map /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts \
  --ext-mount-map /etc/hostname:/etc/hostname \
  --ext-mount-map /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf
```

Basically, we would prefer the docker native and runc. 
But both do not support predump now.
the hack way. github.com/marcosnils/runc
but I double the runC version is old.

Comment: sorry about the format. The markdown check make me crazy. And because of reputation, I need to modify the link. github refers to a link.

Comment: I have experimented with the native and of course can confirm that it doesn't support iterative checkpoints. The external way is the only bet however the example pasted here is similar to the one posted on the CRIU wiki which seems a bit outdate. Can you provide some documentation about the --ext-mount-map and its meaning?

Comment: It seems we have the same goal. But sorry that I donot have the answer.https://criu.org/External_bind_mounts,may have some help

Comment: So, let me ask you, where you able to reproduce the example you mention above as c) external way? I get a bunch of errors when I attempt to run the exact same steps.

Comment: I test the my example(more complex than the demo example.) three days ago, and I need to add some options.when you faced a dump failed, try to find the log and check it. if you need more help,visit my blog: xichenpro.com and my contact info.Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi，have you figure out how to do this? Check my hijack code here:https://github.com/hixichen/criu_xichen_modify . after add several lines of code, you can do this very easy.

Comment: Hi, I am still struggling with various experimental versions of both criu and docker. I will check your executable tomorrow as I am really interested in that project. So far I have problem with open tcp connections. I will first experiment with your fork and let you know.

Comment: xichen how can I contact you? Is it possible to upload sample code of how you can accomplish basic tasks with your forked criu? I ll try to contact you externally if I can.

Comment: Can we do this incremental checkpointing in runc with full dumps?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the process running try `docker checkpoint create --leave-running=true`